# Issue with silverlight screen loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0

I am having a view composed of partial views. Please look at the following image -
[image: Software Genius Inc]

I am using JQuery for navigating left side panel. Each right side screen is a partial view. Everything works perfectly. The problem here is with the silverlight screen embed in the following view. Lets check the image -

[image]

Each time i click on the code link the silverlight screen is reloaded washing out my contents that i entered in the code editor.

Following is the code -

```
    <div id="scanneredit" class="tabs">
             <div class="Navigation">
                <div class="header"><%=DataOrModel %> Sections</div>
    <ul> 
<li>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <img alt="Code" src="../../Content/Images/Icon_Code.png" />
                        <a href="#code">Code</a>
                        <%if (Model.ErrorInSection == 5)
                          {%>
                        <div class="ErrorIndicator">
                            <img alt="General Details" src="../../Content/Images/no.png" /> 
                        </div>
                        <%}
                          else if (Model.ErrorInSection > 5)
                          {%>
                          <div class="ErrorIndicator">
                            <img alt="General Details" src="../../Content/Images/ok.png" /> 
                        </div>
                        <%} %>
                    </div>
                </li>
 </ul>

    </div>

    <div class="tab">
                <%Html.BeginForm("Create", "Scanner", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createscanner" });%>

    .
    .
    .
    <div id="code" class="scanner"> 
                <h3>Code</h3>
                <h5>Define core logic of a <%=DataOrModel%>.</h5>
                <hr  />
                <% 
                Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Scanner/ScannerCode.ascx", new ViewDataDictionary(Model) );
                %>

                </div>

    .
    .
    .
    </div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does this relate to Silverlight?